# How do I use shared preferences in a fragment on Android?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment and I want to store the Facebook id in a shared preference. I can't write mode private in the get preference function. And also I want to access this shared preference in another fragment. How can I do so?

Here is my code...

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session,
                     SessionState state,
                     Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        t = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        p = (ProfilePictureView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profilePictureView1);
                        p.setProfileId(user.getId());
                        s = user.getName();
                        t.setText(s);
                        s1 = user.getId();

                        private void SavePreferences(String key,String value)
                        {
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString(key, value);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
```

Comment: Try `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` instead.

Comment: use preferencemanager.getsharedpreference(context)...

Comment: Correct the formatting of your code - (hint: no horizontal scrollbar, etc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `Shared Preferences` inside a `Fragment`; see below.

First write in `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
edt.putString("facebook_id", id);
edt.commit();
```

Here id is the string containing the Facebook id which you've got, and 0 indicates private_mode.

Second, to read the Facebook id stored in `SharedPreference` in another `Fragment`:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String id = pref.getString("facebook_id", "empty");
```

Here empty is the default value returned if facebook_id is null inside `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do like,

```
editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("yourtextvalueKey", test);
                        editor.commit();
```

and to get

```
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = prefs.getString("yourtextvalueKey", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create a separate session class:

  ```
  public class Session {
  private static String PREF_NAME = "Memory";
  private static String FBID = "FBID ";
  public static boolean saveSessionId(String FBID , Context context) {
  Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit();
  editor.putString(FBID , FBID);
  return editor.commit();
  }

  public static String getSessionId(Context context) {
  SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(
          PREF_NAME, 0);
  return savedSession.getString(FBID , null);
  }
  }
  ```

Call the save method when you want to save the ID. Then, in the same way, call the `getsessionid` method to get that ID.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `SavePreferences` method as follows:

```
private static String MY_PREFS = "My_Preference";
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            MY_PREFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getSharedPrefs();
}

private void getSharedPrefs() {
    sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            Data.MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // check for all to be loaded here
    boolean isValid = false;

    int posImage = 0;

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Data.COLUMN_IMAGENUMBER)) {
        posImage = sharedpreferences.getInt(Data.COLUMN_IMAGENUMBER, 0);
        if (posImage >= 0 || posImage < Data.PICS.length) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    } else {
        isValid = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(Data.COLUMN_IMAGENUMBER, cv.currentPuzzleImagePosition);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: lint will tell you to consider using apply

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. This is enough for this `Shared preference`, and it works either you work in activity or `Fragment`. `Shared preference` can not reflect or can not effective either Activity or `Fragment`.

For more click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561490/storing-public-key-in-sharedpreferences-and-retrieving-it/33561735#33561735)