# How to store session id from java server in android application?

Tags: android, session, session-cookies, persistent-storage

I have an android application which on successful login gets session id in json string. Now I want to store that session id in cookie and retrieve that cookie to send again in further request.
Now please tell me how to persistently store the cookie and retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at SharedPrefferences.This will help you
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: i have already used it... i am storing the session id in shared preference and again sending that session id in json string but at server side, it always create a new session but i wanted that old session id to be retained until the application is active

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
  public class Session {
private static String PREF_NAME = "Memory";
private static String FBID = "FBID ";

public static boolean saveSessionId(String FBID , Context context) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(FBID , FBID );
    return editor.commit();
}

public static String getSessionId(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREF_NAME, 0);
    return savedSession.getString(FBID , null);
}
}
```

[How do I use shared preferences in a fragment on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720089/how-to-use-shared-preferences-in-fragment-in-android/21720123#21720123)

Comment: I have already used it... i am storing the session id in shared preference and again sending that session id in json string but at server side, it always create a new session but i wanted that old session id to be retained until the application is active ...

Answer (score 0):

Session id is maintained by server for each session i.e. session id remains same for a session. Successful login marks the beginning of a session and a successful logout marks the end of a session. Another way, a session can end is through timeout.

For e.g. when you log in, you receive a session id. Now, you can use this session id to make other requests. This session id expires when you log out or you timeout. The value of timeout depends on how critical the app is i.e. if its a banking app then the server will timeout a session within minutes, whereas an e-commerce app can have a longer timeout (Beyond scope: server caches session)

In your case, please check whether you are timing out or logging out. If neither, then there is an issue with server not maintaining the session id. Remember, a server generates a unique session id for every session.